# Lucene suggestSimilar method from SpellChecker class always return null

Tags: java, lucene

I have `test1.txt` file with next content:
`aaa`

So I'm trying to find `a` symbol by using `SpellChecker` class:

```
        File dir = new File("/home/iurii/TestFolder/");
        Directory directory = FSDirectory.open(dir);
        SpellChecker spellChecker = new SpellChecker(directory);
        Dictionary dictionary = new PlainTextDictionary(new File("/home/iurii/TestFolder/test1.txt"));
        IndexWriterConfig config = new IndexWriterConfig(Version.LATEST, new StandardAnalyzer());
        spellChecker.indexDictionary(dictionary, config, false);
        String[] results = spellChecker.suggestSimilar("a", 2);
```

The main problem here that array `results` is always empty. What is wrong with my code?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: wild guess here...possibly because the Levenstein distance between `a` and `aaa` is too large? What happens if you try a word that is closer to `aaa` like `aab`?

Comment: when I put `aab` then it works ok. But it's still not clear for me, could you please explain why this is not working: `spellChecker.suggestSimilar("aaa", 1)`?

Comment: Because you asked it to suggest similar terms.  It won't return the same term along with the suggestions.

Comment: Thanks, could you please write an answer and I mark this question as resolved.